# Android build.gradle - Libraries clashing

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am Developing an android application and using a library say A. and I have another library say B which internally uses A. Because of this, I get Duplicate zip entry error on my build. How do i exclude libraries from 3rd party libraries or how do i get around this issue?

Comment: Did you make any modifications to A? I'll usually discard A and just use the one inside B.

Comment: both are different versions. What if i want to use the one outside B and not use the one inside B

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude the modules you don't need from a dependency with `exclude module`:

```
compile (project(':B')) {
    exclude module: 'A'
}
```